# Make ForEach Finish Before Each Loop

Tags: javascript, promise

This piece of code waits for 2s and then console.log's each element straight away. How can I change this forEach to wait for every timeout to finish before looping over to the next one? So what I want is for 2s to go by, then it logs "1", then another 2s goes by, then it logs "2" etc. I looked at promises (half implemented here) but I don't understand how it works.

```js
MyArray = [1, 2, 3];

MyArray.forEach(async element => {
    await setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(element);
    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Async does not work with `setTimeout`, you can return a promise that resolves later and when that resolves return the next value and so on. Reduce can do this for you:

```
const MyArray = [1, 2, 3];
const later = (howLong, element) =>
  new Promise(
    resolve =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(element);
        resolve(element)
      }, howLong)
  );

MyArray.reduce(
  (all, element) =>
    all.then(
      () => later(2000, element)
    ),
  Promise.resolve()
).then(()=>console.log("done"));
```

The following is in parallel:

```
const MyArray = [1, 2, 3];

Promise.all(
  MyArray.map(element =>
    new Promise(
      resolve=>
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(element);
          resolve(element)
        }, 2000)
    )
  )
).then(
  results=>console.log("results",results)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to run the promises in series, where each promise will resolve after 2 seconds and then next one will run

```
MyArray.reduce(function(chain, element) {
  return chain.then(function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     setTimeout(() => {
       console.log(element);
       resolve(element)
     }, 2000);
    });
  })
}, Promise.resolve([]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use a simple recursive asynchronous sequencer as follows;

```js
var sequenceAsync = ([d,...ds]) => d !== void 0 && asyncTask(d).then(v => (console.log(v), sequenceAsync(ds))),
    asyncTask     = n => new Promise(v => setTimeout(v, 1000, n)),
    datas         = [1,2,3];

sequenceAsync(datas);
```

`void 0` is a perfect `undefined` value to check for `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function resolveAfter2Seconds(i) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(i);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall(MyArray) {
  for(var i=0; i<MyArray.length; i++){
  var result = await resolveAfter2Seconds(MyArray[i]);
  console.log(result);
  }
  
 
}
var MyArray = [1, 2, 3];
asyncCall(MyArray);
```